# C# ASP.NET Server Tag is Not Well Formed

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-web-developer

I'm getting this error on these two lines specifically.

Any ideas as to why? I've searched the threads and nothing seems to help me here.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" name="password" size="25" placeholder="Password" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="PasswordConfirm" name="passwordconfirm" size="25" placeholder="Confirm Password" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this ( Remove name attribute)

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password"  size="25" placeholder="Password" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="PasswordConfirm" size="25" placeholder="Confirm Password" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
```